Is it possible to combine two CryptoKeys into one?
I'm looking for a way to combine two CryptoKeys into one via XOR or deriveKey. Is there a way to do so directly without exporting keys via exportKey, combining them and then improting again?
The documentation doesn't seem to support it. As far as I understood, there is no way to do it for extractable=false. Is it so?
